# UIView layoutConstraint weird behavior, sticks on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios-autolayout

I have a tableview as a subview (contentView is superview). It has a top-constraint with the value of 190, but it keeps sticking to the top (origin.y is 0.0) on my iPhone 6. However, on my iPhone X, it works perfectly normal.

```
- (void)adjustHeightOfViews {

    //adjust contentview-height to tableview-height
    self.tableViewTopConstraint.active = YES;
    self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 190;

    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < [_cellTitles count]; i ++) {
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant += [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]].size.height;

        }        
        self.contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant + 500.0f;


    self.tableViewTopConstraint.constant = 190;
}
```

The viewheights are set in my adjustHeightOfViews method, which I call in viewDidLayoutSubviews (I tried here calling the method in viewDidAppear and everywhere else, doesn't solve the issue).

What is the issue here?

**EDIT**

The problem disappears when I disable [cell layOutIfNeeded] in my cellForRow (which I need, of course), so weird!

-> the tableView has a functioning topConstraint after that

Comment: did you try calling. self.view.layoutIfNeeded() . ? at the end of this method

Comment: I am testing it on a device.

Comment: you should not calculate height of tableview in cell for row. calculate it on the basis of total counts of your cells items. and call it somewhere else and then reload your tableview. then it should work fine.

Comment: The method: adjustHeightOfViews is called in viewDidLayoutSubviews, I am not calculating anything in my cellForRow, I only need the [cell layOutIfNeeded] method there :/